Why can I log in with Putty SSH as one non-root user, but not as a new non-root user?
I already have a user "tom" set up on my Debian system, which was created when first installing the OS. This user is able to successfully log in via SSH using Putty.
Now I have set up a new user, with:
root@dmydebian:~# useradd -p mypass -u 1001 -s /bin/bash newuser

But when trying to log in to the machine as this user through Putty, I receive an Access Denied error after entering the password. Why is user "tom" able to log in, but user "newuser" is not?
Note, if I instead log in as "tom", I am able to then switch users with su - newuser. But cannot log directly in.

Here are the users in the /etc/passwd file:
cat /etc/passwd
...
tom:x:1000:1000:Tom,,,:/home/tom:/bin/bash
newuser:x:1001:1001::/:/bin/bash

Here is the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile     .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin prohibit-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#       X11Forwarding no
#       AllowTcpForwarding no
#       PermitTTY no
#       ForceCommand cvs server

Here are the logs:
tom@docker-debian:~$ ssh -v newuser@192.168.0.65
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.65 [192.168.0.65] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/tom/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.0.65:22 as 'newuser'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/tom/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: sntrafdssafdag1x25519-sha512@openssh.com
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:4w3eizL2sw1oiRyadsgasdgadsgdafgdagfBuyUQ1NpRSvGATY
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/tom/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '192.168.0.65' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/tom/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_packet_send2_wrapped: resetting send seqnr 3
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: ssh_packet_read_poll2: resetting read seqnr 3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info:
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /home/tom/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
newuser@192.168.0.65's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.


Post your sudo file. Also post the OpenSSH verbose logs as the user in question connects

Hopefully I'm not blind and missed it, but can you add a line to the end with AllowUsers tom without a # at the beginning? Then try again?

@CaturdaySaint The user "tom" is able to connect, but the user called "newuser" is not able to connect. If AllowUsers option was the solution, then I would expect to see "AllowUsers tom" in the config file, and would need to add "newuser" to the list as well. But since there is nothing there, I don't understand how "tom" is able to connect successfully.

@Ramhound I have posted the logs in the question. I do not have a sudoers file, because I do not have the sudo package installed, am not using it.

I see a configuration file. I see a passwd file. I don’t see a verbose server log from when the user in question was connecting to the server.

@Ramhound Actually, one thing I noticed is that the user "tom" has a directory called ~/.ssh/ which contains a file called "known_hosts". The "newuser" has no such directory or file. Is this something which has to be manually set up for each user?

Re the known_hosts thing - that is not your problem. That file is used to identify ssh connections made FROM the machine so a warning can pop up if the server key changes.

Have you looked at the log files - especially audit.log or similar?  I have seen problems with ssh logins related to selinux in the past - although from memory that was more around inability to read public key files.

@KamilMaciorowski no it doesn't. Password is "mypass1234" for testing.

Are you trying to not use a public key? Your password authentication fails which suggests either the user does it exist or the password does not exist. You are using the username “Tom”’s password with “newuser”?

You set newuser’s home directory to /. Why? Is this intentional?

From the useradd man page...
-p, --password PASSWORD
  The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.
  Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.
  You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.

You would appear to have given a plain text password & the system expects it to be encryped.
You can see this if you grep the user in /etc/shadow.
I have not come across any utility which generate the encrypted password string from plain, so your only route would be to run sudo passwd <user> & set it that way.

Perfect, great spot! This now works, thanks a bunch. I didn't see anything in the logs that was indicating this..
